# Simple makefile for MPI-based C program

Tags: makefile, mpi

I am writing my first MPI-based C program. I have four files namely, MPI_Program.c and Helper.c, and their corresponding .h files. MPI_Program.c includes mpi.h and Helper.h.

I wrote the following simple makefile to compile MPI_Program but I get the error "No rule to make target mpi.h"

Here's the makefile:

```
# Rules to produce the target

all: MPI_Program

MPI_Program: MPI_Program.o Helper.o 
     mpixlc MPI_Program.o Helper.o -f machineFile -std=c99 -g -o MPI_Program


# Rules to produce the object files

Helper.o: Helper.c Helper.h
     gcc -c Helper.c -std=c99 -g

MPI_Program.o: MPI_Program.c MPI_Program.h Helper.h mpi.h
     mpixlc -c MPI_Program.c -std=c99 -g -f machineFile
```

I am certainly missing something...Can someone please advise.

Comment: Are you sure `mpi.h` is present in the directory where you run Make?

Comment: I'm assuming mpi.h is the actual MPI library header file. In which case you need to list it with a full path if you want to include it in the prerequisites list like that. ... That being said you probably don't actually want to do that that way (you might want to look into the automatic dependency generation stuff that MadScientist has on his site though).